# How to get warning/error when using logical or operator with literal strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Is there a way to get a compiler or linter error or warning for the following code:

```js
const isValid = myValue.includes("substrA" || "substrB");
```

The `"substrA" || "substrB"` part always evaluates to `"substrA"` so I can't imagine when someone would write this code intentionally. In my particular case, the intended code was:

```js
const isValid = myValue.includes("substrA") || myValue.includes("substrB");
```

Of course, you can catch such an error with tests. It would be even better if a warning was generated for it by the TypeScript compiler or by ESLint.

As expected, the compiler doesn't complain because it's perfectly valid JavaScript/TypeScript code. However, I couldn't find an ESlint rule for it either.

Is there a way have a warning generated for the code in the first code snippet above?

Comment: Yeah, if they're *literals*, that's the sort of thing a linter should pick up. If you don't find one (I didn't in a [quick scan](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)), you might write one for ESLint and submit a PR.

Comment: [ FWIW, rather than scanning the string twice (though if it's a short string it doesn't matter): `const isValid = /substrA|substrB/.test(myValue);` ]

Comment: I think you are entering an area here where the machine intelligence will start to interfere with the programmer's intentions. even if you could create such an ESLint condition - who is to tell that there won't ever be a slightly more convoluted case where this type of construct was intended and justified? There will always be semantical cases that cannot be filtered out automatically in the same way as an algorithm will hardly be able to pick out a Pulitzer prize winning book from an arbitrary collection of texts.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann - Normally I'm not a fan of overdoing checks like this, but there is literally no case where `stringLiteral || x` ever makes sense. There is no clever code waiting to be found there. :-) *String*, yes, of course, but not *string literal*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "if they're literals, that's the sort of thing a linter should pick up": What about if these literals were created by some PHP process generating the JavaScript? And one of the strings might be empty - I am only constructing some "convoluted case" here, I am not advocating it ;-).

Comment: @CarstenMassmann - Then fix the PHP process. :-) But I do see your point about generated code. But do we really run linters on generated code?